# My Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit OS put password itself

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, login, login-screen

I sat in my chair to use my computer, and when I started Windows OS, I noticed that Windows set a password by itself and I'm sure that I have not set any password before.

[image: An example of login screen]

Okay, let's have a look the image above.

1- The green circle at the bottom left corner indicates the "Number 1" button (The Ease of Access button)

2- The blue circle at the bottom right left corner indicates the "Number 2" button (The "shut down" button)

3- The black circle at the bottom right left corner indicates "Number 3" button (The button which is symbolized with an up-arrow and is next to shut down button - The button for showing context menu which contains options like "Restart" - )

And this image is not from my computer; I used it only to represent login screen.

I wrote down these Number 1, Number 2, and Number 3 tags because I will use them downside to explain my problem. (I completely created it by myself; they do not have a serious meaning.)

A classical login password screen appears when I start Windows, and I am even not able to click the login button.
Whatever I write into that password box when I click on the login button, nothing happens.
And unfortunately the operating system shuts itself down at every time after 1 minute and 2 -3 seconds -Even if I really do nothing, just sit down and wait- I measured the time.

The buttons which I tagged as Number 2 and Number 3 does not give any reaction except for clicking animation when I click on them. 
But when I double click Number 3 button, a screen appears just like in the image.
I tried writing "Administrator" in the username box and leaving empty the password box. It didn't work. Just like at the main screen, the login button did not give any reaction like "Your username or password is invalid." The system can not even be able to show this message, unfortunately.

The things I've tried to solve the problem so far are as follows:

1- I copied cmd.exe file in C:\Windows\System32 folder as utilman.exe and I could be able to access command prompt in login screen without logging in by clicking "The Ease of Access Center" button which is at the lower-left corner.
(See the image upside, it is the button which I tagged as "Number 1 Button")
Then to set a password for my active user, I wrote this command (my username is ASUS32):

> net user ASUS32 123

By doing this, I thought I could set the password as 123 and login to the system by just typing 123 in the password box and clicking the login button.
But It did not work because the command gave the following error:

> System error 1722. The RPC server is unavailable.

I have not ever seen an error like this before on any computer when I have given this command.

Note:"takeown" command even gives the same error. I tried this command to take ownership of the files in C:\Windows\System32\config - I just wanted to try it if it works... -

I thought that the whole fault could be about this RPC server error.
And to validate that, I opened the services window by typing services.msc command on command prompt and I checked that whether if the RPC server is active or not. Surprisingly, it was active. But it was still giving the error of System error 1722 even it was active.

2- So I started to search for different ways to solve this problem, and I found a program which is named as "Active Password Changer Professional." I burned it onto a CD and inserted into CD reader of my computer.
I booted up from that CD and applied required processes to reset my password which is set to ASUS32 user. A success message appeared which said that "The process is completed successfully."
I shut down my computer and restarted it. And the OS was asking the password still.

3- I started to think that the fault was about the registry files, which is in the C:\Windows\System32\config folder. I tried some processes about this.
These processes are:

a. I copied the files which are in the C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack folder into C:\Windows\System32\config folder. I overwrote the ones in the RegBack folder on the ones  in the config folder (Of course I backed up the old files.) I restarted my computer. It didn't work.

b. There were files that have the same name but different as letter case like that -in C:\Windows\System32\config folder- :

> ```
>  SYSTEM
>  system
>  SOFTWARE
>  software
>  .....
> ```

All of the uppercase-written ones had a size of 1 KB. So I suspected that these were the wrong files and I deleted the duplicates which were written in uppercase.
     I replaced the left with the ones in the RegBack folder. 
     I restarted my computer. It didn't work.

Note: I know that if the operating system is inaccessible, these processes can not be done. So I did these processes from Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit OS - which is in installed on the same hard disk drive but a different partition -

4- I tried to use System Restore Tool to solve this problem via Repair Disk, but the system couldn't be able to find any System Restore points on the partition.

5- I tried to boot in Safe Mode but the same login screen appeared again. I also tried to give that command:

> net user ASUS32 123

But it gave the same error with the above:

> System error 1722. The RPC server is unavailable.

6- I tried to run the chkdsk command within the corrupted windows os and it correctly worked after rebooting. But it couldn't solve the problem.

7- I checked the situation of the disk by giving that command within the corrupted windows:

> wmic diskdrive get status

At my first try, the command gave nothing as output.
At my second try, the result was the same.
But at my third try, the command gave an error like that:

> The system can not be able to run the specified path.

8- I also tried Startup Recovery by inserting the Recovery Disc but It couldn't solve the problem.

9- I tried to enable the built-in Administrator account via command prompt on the corrupted Windows partition by using the following command:

> net user administrator /active:yes

But whenever I use a command which starts with "net" phrase, I get the same following error:

> System error 1722. The RPC server is unavailable.

So I thought that maybe I could enable built-in account via Rescue Disc.
I opened the command prompt after I booted the system with Rescue Disc and I gave the same command as well.
The system did not output any fault message. I restarted my computer but I couldn't be able to see any option that indicates "Administrator" account on login screen.

So, these are the solution ways which I have tried so far.

Note: I haven't tried Repair Install method yet.

The problem still continues and I can't solve it by myself.

Comment: Time to reinstall Windows....

Comment: The image is not accessible.  Please upload using the upload screenshot functionality.  In any event, Windows does not automatically set a password, if you cannot access your normal user profile just enable the built-in Administrator by booting to a Windows 7 instalation media.

Comment: @python_pardus - I am absolutely positive the problem is with the link.  Please upload the image to imgur using the built-in upload image capabilities of the site.

Comment: @Ramhound - Okay, I added the same image by using two more links. All of the links specifies the same image. The second one is uploaded with built-in upload image capabilities of site. However, I can reach the first and third link but can't reach the second link. Please check the situation.

Comment: Please refresh the page, so you don't overwrite the grammatical fixes (again), that I spent 10 minutes making

Comment: I didn't know that the warning message I saw which is shown up indicated that the question was being edited by someone else so I didn't refresh the page. I'm sorry about it. It won't be happen (again) :) And thank you for fixing it as grammatically.

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>F8</kbd> and try to boot in Safe mode. If this works try to create a new user
account and see if it can login, as in this case your user profile is corrupted.
If you cannot get into Safe mode, use your hack of getting into the Command
Prompt to do that.

You could also try to use the boot media to rollback to a System Restore
point from before the problem occurred.

Another try is to
[Enable the Built-In Administrator Account](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024429753?redirect=true)
and see if you can use it to boot and do maintenance such as
[sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

If this doesn't work, and as you have done many manipulations, perhaps
[Repair Install](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)
can help, using the most recent Windows 7 boot media (SP2?).
Be careful to operate on the right partition.

I really hate the idea of doing Repair Install on such an old system. Use first on another computer a product such as [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) to create its boot CD/USB and boot it on this computer to create a backup image of the system disk on external media. This way you can always at least come back to the current state.

Before starting, use the other Windows 7 to take a backup image of the bad installation.
Do also `chkdsk` to verify the partition, and check the disk's SMART data
(if this is supported on the hardware).

Comment: @python_pardus - All vital information necessary to answer your question should be in the question body, instead of a comment, comments are designed to be temporary.

Comment: @Ramhound - I will edit my question as providing the vital details, thank you for warning.

Comment: @harrymc - For further details please read the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: You could also try to use the boot media to rollback to a System Restore point from before the problem occurred.

Comment: I will try it but are you sure that I can find a System Restore point via boot media although I couldn't find any System Restore points with Rescue Disc?

Comment: I didn't know that you already tried to rollback. If there are no System Restore points from a week ago this means that it was allocated too little disk space. I added above the idea of trying to enable the built-in Admin account and use it for maintenance. I really hate the idea of doing Repair Install on such an old system, but after that I have no more ideas. I added info above for doing disk backup first.

Comment: I tried to enable the built-in Administrator but I couldn't be able to do this due to RPC server error when I gave "net user administrator /active:yes" command. So I tried to enable built-in administrator with Rescue Disc. I gave the same command via Command-Prompt - which is provided by Rescue Disc- but nothing changed. I can't see an option which indicates "Administrator" account, unfortunately. I will update the question text as well.